requestAnimationFrame and its lifecycle
I realized that I was confused with requestAnimationFrame, although some time ago I thought I understood how it works.
So what is the essence of my problem:
They say that requestAnimationFrame, namely its callback, will be called before the rendering stages, that is, calling requestAnimationFrame does not mean that the browser will run to execute the callback function passed to it right now.
However, if we take this code:
const run = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame((timeStamp) => {
    console.log(timestamp);
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
  })
};
run();

and if we run on a completely empty page, we will see how the timestamps will be printed in the console, but why if the page is completely empty, there is no reason to render. The reason?
Okay, let's look at the specification, it says you need to wait for rendering opportunity before starting the task related to rendering, where our requestAnimationFrame will appear. But the code above should not be printed due to the lack of a rendering opportunity reason. Or is the reason exist?
An explanation is needed.

It's in the name requestAnimationFrame. It's not just onanimationframe.

@Kaiido You're hinting at a name. Let me object, here algorithm there are no lines at all that the browser should receive information, which, for example, will be a trigger for rendering opportunity.

If you are rendering a completely empty page, you are still rendering. The fact that you can run any javascript code, even call the "run" function means that the page has rendered.

A rendering opportunity in my opinion should be automatic. How will you get a video to work when unless browser renders the update at highest possible frequency (according to its refresh rate).
Although it is not detailed upon, I think the below holds significance:

A navigable's rendering opportunities are determined based on hardware constraints such as display refresh rates and other factors such as page performance or whether its active document's visibility state is "visible". Rendering opportunities typically occur at regular intervals.

This is what I speak of Rendering opportunities typically occur at regular intervals.. Typically is used because there are instances when browser is not free to render in the upcoming interval, and that is when we lose frames.
So I think it is the browser's job to generate rendering opportunities, and the event loop spec mentions that for every rendering opportunity animation frame callbacks are supposed to be run:


I understand that rendering opportunity is automatic, the browser decides for itself what this opportunity is for it. The quote you give from the specification simply says that the update cannot be more frequent than the screen update - because if it is more then it is pointless. And well, step 14, yes, I saw it, I said about it that later the requestAnimationFrame will appear in the rendering task. Based on what you wrote, I have a question, what is the criterion for rendering opportunity? That is, I want to specifically know the reasons why the rendering task is being started

why the rendering task is being started? We just saw that it is automatic right. I hope we are not comparing it with a React render. That is a very different layer of abstraction and that will not run here, same can be said for other frontend libraries/frameworks. This rendering is browser level, where the browser should update the content of what is on the screen.

requestAnimationFrame in itself changes nothing on the screen. The visual changes are because of operation X which can be other property/attribute/DOM changes. the result of requestAnimationFrame running is that the operation X has a well define frame in time to run
